# How to use stylesheets with custom QGraphicsItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to figure our how to get a property from the stylesheet to use it in the paint function of a QGraphicsItem.

I have previously used custom css properties for regular QWidgets using the same approach as in the code below. However the `set_background_color` function is never called. Is there a workaround or any other way to use a stylesheet for QGraphicsItem?

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import QGraphicsRectItem, QColor, QBrush


class NodeItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    background_color_value = QColor()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NodeItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paint(self, painter, style, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.get_background_color())
        brush = QBrush(self.get_background_color())
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(-10, -10, 20, 20, 5, 5)

    def get_background_color(self):
        return self.background_color_value

    def set_background_color(self, color):
        self.background_color_value = color

    background_color = QtCore.Property(QColor, get_background_color, set_background_color,
                                       designable=True, scriptable=True)
```

**Edit**
this is what the stylesheet looks like:

```
NodeItem {
    qproperty-background_color: #dd9900;
}
```

Apparently it does not work because QGraphicsRectItem does not inherit QObject. Is there another way?

Comment: Why _would_ `set_background_color` be called? It's impossible to tell from the code you've posted.

Comment: It should get called when the property is set from the stylesheet. This is part of qt's [property system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html).

Comment: @BoshWash, Why not then inherit your item from `QObject` too?

Comment: I tried, it didn't change anything, strange.

Comment: @BoshWash. Sorry, I assumed you'd already read the documentation and understood how properties work. A fairly simple workaround would be to use a proxy object to hold the properties and relay stylesheet changes via signals.

Comment: Assuming [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55843-Style-sheet-for-QGraphicsItem) link you can`t use stylesheets on `QGraphicsItem`s. You may object that you just need to match regular `QObject` sublclass and set regular property, but stylesheets are applied to the hierarchy of widgets, but your scene item is just an inner entity of qt graphics framework and stylesheet know nothing about it

Comment: @dwrd, thanks you, that explains why it doesn't work with subclassing `QOobject`

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you as well. If nothing else works this is the route I will go.